# How to get the exit code value from a module function?

Tags: powershell

I have placed a module into my user profile directory. The organization requires my home directory to be on a network share.

```
16:06:09.74 \\COMPNAME\SHNAME\Users\lit  H:\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyUtils
H:>type MyUtils.psm1
function MyFunc()
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param()

    Write-Host "now from myfunc"
    return 8
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function MyFunc
```

When I run `MyFunc` it appears to operate as intended. However, `$LASTEXITCODE` is always `Null`.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> MyFunc
now from myfunc
8
PS C:\src\powershell> if (!$LASTEXITCODE) { Write-Host "LASTEXITCODE is null"}
LASTEXITCODE is null
```

If I use `exit 8`, then my interactive host immediately exits. Same thing using `$Host.SetShouldExit`.

Comment: `$LASTEXITCODE` is for native applications and for `.ps1` scripts, not for functions.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Ok. If I open a PowerShell interactive host and invoke a function, is there any way to get an exit code value? Must I invoke a cmdlet (.ps1) script in order to get the function return value?

Comment: Again, functions does not have exit code to get. And if you talking about pipeline output, then you need to assign it to variable or pass to next command by pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try simply assigning the value to a variable, e.g.:

```
[Int32] $myRc = myfunc;
$myRc;
```

The fact that the '8' is appearing on the console shows that PowerShell is resorting to **Out-Default**, as you haven't told it what to do with the value.

Of course, if you want to do things the PowerShell way, you *should* use **Write-Output** in a function, if the function is going to be used as a cmdlet, as opposed to a "helper" function.

Good luck!